# Add execution to plugin defined in parent pom

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, parent-pom

I have a parent pom.xml file which has a build section like so:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
            <version>${checkstyle.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

In the child pom, I want to effectively add an `executions` node to the `plugin`, but without having to respecify the `version` and `dependencies` nodes - is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add in your child pom:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>checkstyle-check</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  <plugins>
<build>
```

The difference is path where you define plugin

- in `build/pluginManagement/plugins` - you have only configuration
- in `build/plugins` - you declare what you want to execute

Even more you can also move `executions` to `pluginManagement`,
then in child you can have:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  <plugins>
<build>
```

The nodes for plugin configuration from `pluginManagement` and `plugins` and all child are merged to effective `pom`.

You can always check how your `effective` pom will look:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```